# rsync hangs while transferring some files in git repo

Tags: linux, rsync

I am transferring files uing rsync line this -
$ rsync -avz SRC/ joe@phx2:/home/joe/SRC/  --delete

```
build/test/.git/objects/pack/pack-5985ff25d18a2555ed520a8f3684b55697c7ee6d.idx
build/test/.git/objects/pack/pack-5985ff25d18a2555ed520a8f3684b55697c7ee6d.pack
```

rsync just hangs at this message, Am I doing anything wrong ?

Comment: The *.pack files are usually quite big. Try adding the `--progress` option to your rsync call, which will show you actual transfer speeds and file sizes.

Comment: thanks knittl for the hint ..

Answer (score 0):

rsync doesn't hang. Your .pack and .idx files change somewhat completely - making rsync's incremental hashing algorithm useless. So rsync has upload whole file after checking every chuck. Eventually it adds more time then simple transfer.